# WireGuard wg-quick down breaks DNS settings on Ubuntu

Tags: networking, ubuntu, vpn, dns, wireguard

I am using wg-quick on Ubuntu 19.04 to connect with WireGuard to my server.

On my client side I am specifying the DNS servers.

```
dns = 1.1.1.1
```

When I am using `wg-quick down` to disconnect my local DNS settings are brocken and I can not resolve any websites.

How can I disconnect and use the original DNS settings?

Answer (score 0):

This fixes the DNS resolution issue on my ubuntu 20.04

```
sudo systemd-resolve --interface wlp0s20f3 --set-dns 1.1.1.1
sudo service systemd-resolved restart
```

replace `wlp0s20f3` with your own interface. You can find your interface from the list returned when you run `ip a`